# Iterate over rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example:

[image]

I want the cash remaining values to go into the amount available values in the next row, and subsequently for every other row but I'm unsure of how to go about doing this.

Comment: `df.fillna(115.8)`?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you could use pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and pass an appropriate lambda function which takes the `cash_remaining` value from the previous row as argument, e.g. using .loc or .iloc.

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on whether there is some additional logic for each month or not:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'date': [dt(2008, 4, 30), dt(2008, 5, 3), dt(2008, 6, 30), dt(2008, 7, 31), dt(2008, 8, 29)],
    'NYSEARCA:PYZ': [36.37, 38.52, 35.82, 35.80, 34.86],
    'amount_available': [2100] + [np.nan]*4,
    'amount_spent': [1984.2] + [np.nan]*4,
    'cash_remaining': [115.8] + [np.nan]*4
})


method_1 = df.copy()
# if there is "row-by-row" dependencies
for i, row in method_1.iterrows():
    if not np.isnan(row['cash_remaining']):
        cash_rem = row['cash_remaining']
    else:
        # dummy additional time-series dependent logic
        cash_rem_old = cash_rem
        spent = round(np.random.rand(1).item() * 20, 2) # whatever
        cash_rem = cash_rem_old - spent

        row[['amount_available', 'amount_spent', 'cash_remaining']] = [cash_rem_old, spent, cash_rem]
        method_1.iloc[i] = row

# if values just need to be copied over
method_2 = df.copy()
target = method_2['cash_remaining'][0]
method_2.loc[1:, ['amount_available', 'amount_spent', 'cash_remaining']] = [target, 0.0, target]

print(method_1)
#         date  NYSEARCA:PYZ  amount_available  amount_spent  cash_remaining
# 0 2008-04-30         36.37           2100.00       1984.20          115.80
# 1 2008-05-03         38.52            115.80         14.81          100.99
# 2 2008-06-30         35.82            100.99          0.96          100.03
# 3 2008-07-31         35.80            100.03         17.65           82.38
# 4 2008-08-29         34.86             82.38          7.24           75.14

print(method_2)
#         date  NYSEARCA:PYZ  amount_available  amount_spent  cash_remaining
# 0 2008-04-30         36.37            2100.0        1984.2           115.8
# 1 2008-05-03         38.52             115.8           0.0           115.8
# 2 2008-06-30         35.82             115.8           0.0           115.8
# 3 2008-07-31         35.80             115.8           0.0           115.8
# 4 2008-08-29         34.86             115.8           0.0           115.8
```